# Convert html page to pdf without degrading the quality

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf

i'm trying to convert a html document to a pdf using javascript but the quality is significally lower than it should be ( text is blurry, colors are not pure ,... ) even though it's displaying fine in my web browser.

here is the pdf generator function i'm using  :

```
public convertToPDF()
{
  let domElement = this.pdfTable.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  html2canvas(domElement).then(canvas => {
    // Few necessary setting options
    var imgWidth = 210;
    var pageHeight = 750;
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width; 

    var heightLeft = imgHeight;

    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
    var position = 0;
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'JPG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
    pdf.save('new-file.pdf'); // Generated PDF
  });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the image resolution is too low. Did you try using a bigger number for `imgWidth` 210 pixels doesn't sound a lot for an A4 size image - approximately 1 pixel per mm or 25 pixels per inch (assuming portrait orientation.)

Comment: @phuzi done that, but the quality is bad

Comment: What `imgWidth`s have you tried?

Comment: var imgWidth = 450;
  var imgHeight = 650;

and i changed the pramater from 'mm' to 'px',
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'px', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'JPG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)

the image covers the whole pdf document, but the quality is bad

   

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'px', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF

Comment: At 300dpi there would be approximately 2,480 dots  in 210mm. Your image size is still way too small. Try an image size closer to 2,500 x 3,600. Imagine putting an image 450 x 650 on your screen, it probably would look low quality once printed out at A4.

Comment: @phuzi so should my html element also have 2500x 3600 px in size?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try setting it in the options html2canvas too.